# How to trigger function when date stored in firestore database is todays date?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, onesignal

I am creating an app where I need to send push notification when today's date matches with the date stored in database in order to send push notification.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

You can use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions), instead of writing an HTTPS Cloud Function that is called via n online CRON Job service. The Cloud Function code stays exactly the same, just the trigger changes.

Scheduled Cloud Functions were not available at the time of writing the initial anwser.

---

Without knowing your data model it is difficult to give a precise answer, but let's imagine, to simplify, that you store in each document a field named `notifDate` with format DDMMYYY and that those documents are store in a Collection named `notificationTriggers`.

You could write an HTTPS Cloud Function as follows:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const moment = require('moment');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendDailyNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    cors(request, response, () => {
  
       const now = moment();
       const dateFormatted = now.format('DDMMYYYY');

       admin.firestore()
       .collection("notificationTriggers").where("notifDate", "==", dateFormatted)
       .get()
       .then(function(querySnapshot) {

           const promises = []; 

           querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
 
               const tokenId = doc.data().tokenId;  //Assumption: the tokenId is in the doc
               const notificationContent = {
                 notification: {
                    title: "...",
                    body: "...",  //maybe use some data from the doc, e.g  doc.data().notificationContent
                    icon: "default",
                    sound : "default"
                 }
              };

              promises
              .push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, notificationContent));      
  
          });
          return Promise.all(promises);
       })
       .then(results => {
            response.send(data)
       })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          response.status(500).send(error)
       });

    });

});
```

You would then call this Cloud Function every day with an online CRON job service like https://cron-job.org/en/.

For more examples on how to send notifications in Cloud Functions, have a look at those SO answers [Sending push notification using cloud function when a new node is added in firebase realtime database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580988/sending-push-notification-using-cloud-function-when-a-new-node-is-added-in-fireb/50581967#50581967), [node.js firebase deploy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377625/node-js-firebase-deploy-error/50377933#50377933) or [Firebase: Cloud Firestore trigger not working for FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51590886/firebase-cloud-firestore-trigger-not-working-for-fcm/51594048#51594048).

If you are not familiar with the use of Promises in Cloud Functions I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

You will note the use of `Promise.all()` in the above code, since you are executing several asynchronous tasks (`sendToDevice()` method) in parallel. This is detailed in the third video mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a Lot man,!
It works . 
But I stuck in another problem

Comment: By the way i am using Onesignal for push notification..! :) :)

Comment: @Eddysapata Happy that I could help you! I would suggest that you create a new Question instead of asking this question as an answer to your first question. Future readers may be "puzzled" by this answer which actually doesn't answer to the question.

Comment: Yes i will .
But did you get it, 
Can you please help me in this.!

Comment: Yes I could probably help you. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Kindly help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347676/in-cloud-function-how-can-i-join-from-another-collection-to-get-data

Comment: Hi, Should this code go inside my index.js file or inside a seperate file?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Cloud Functions Scheduled Triggers
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub

Using a scheduled trigger you can specify how many times to invoke your function by specifying the frequency using the unix-cron format. Then within the function you can do date check and other needed logic

Comment: Don't have any plan to use AppEngine.
Sorry..
Thanks for your time. :)