# In Cloud function how can i join from another collection to get data?

Tags: node.js, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Function to send a notification to mobile device. I have two collection in Firestore `clientDetail` and `clientPersonalDetail`. I have `clientID` same in both of the collection but the date is stored in `clientDetail` and name is stored in clientPersonal.

Take a look:

```
ClientDetail -- startDate
             -- clientID
             .......

ClientPersonalDetail -- name
                     -- clientID
                     .........
```

Here is My full Code:

```
exports.sendDailyNotifications = functions.https.onRequest(  (request, response) => {
var getApplicants = getApplicantList();
console.log('getApplicants', getApplicants);

cors(request, response, () => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("clientDetails")
    //.where("clientID", "==", "wOqkjYYz3t7qQzHJ1kgu")
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let clientObject = {};
        clientObject.clientID = doc.data().clientID;
        clientObject.monthlyInstallment = doc.data().monthlyInstallment;
        promises.push(clientObject);
      });

      return Promise.all(promises);
    }) //below code for notification
    .then(results => {
      response.send(results);
      results.forEach(user => {
        //sendNotification(user);
      });
      return "";
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      response.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

}
);

Above function is showing an object like this

```
{clienId:xxxxxxxxx, startDate:23/1/2019}
```

But I need ClientID not name to show in notification so I'll have to join to clientPersonal collection in order to get name using clientID.
What should do ?

How can I create another function which solely return name by passing clientID as argument, and waits until it returns the name .
Can Anybody please Help.?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do with the list of clients ID? Send it back with the HTTP response? Do you want to use the client name in the notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two extra functions in this occasion to have your code clear. One function that will read all the documents form the collection `ClientDetail` and instead of getting all the fields, will get only the `ClientID`. Then call the other function, that will be scanning all the documents in collection `ClientPersonalDetail` and retrieve only the part with the ClientID. Compare if those two match and then do any operations there if they do so.

You can refer to [Get started with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) documentation on how to create, add and load documents from Firestore.

Your `package,json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.5.1"
  }
}
```

I have did a little bit of coding myself and here is my [example code in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Firestore/collections_documents_fields_nodejs.js). By deploying this Function, will scan all the documents form one Collection and compare the ClientID from the documents in the other collection. When it will find a match it will log a message otherwise it will log a message of not matching IDs. You can use the idea of how this function operates and use it in your code.

Answer (score 4):

> But I need ClientID not name to show in notification so I'll have to join to clientPersonal collection in order to get name using clientID. What should do ?

Unfortunately, there is no JOIN clause in Firestore. Queries in Firestore are shallow. This means that they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from two top-level collection in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one go. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

> How can I create another function which solely return name by passing clientID as argument, and waits until it returns the name.

So the most simple solution I can think of is to first query the database to get the `clientID`. Once you have this id, make another database call (inside the callback), so you can get the corresponding name.

Another solution would be to add the name of the user as a new property under `ClientDetail` so you can query the database only once. This practice is called `denormalization` and is a common practice when it comes to Firebase. If you are new to NoQSL databases, I recommend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA) for a better understanding. It is for Firebase realtime database but same rules apply to Cloud Firestore.

Also, when you are duplicating data, there is one thing that need to keep in mind. In the same way you are adding data, you need to maintain it. With other words, if you want to update/detele an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists.

Comment: I didn't know this mean Denormalisation is normal.
I was a mysql guy , thanks for that link..! 
P.S : I am new to Nosql database.. :)

Answer (score 2):

The "easier" solution would probably be the duplication of data. This is quite common in NoSQL world.

More precisely you would add in your documents in the `ClientDetail` collection the value of the client `name`.

Comment: thought came in my mind also but what if in future i stuck in a problem where one is doomed to join then what would i do that was the reason i was asking this question otherwise by adding another field of name simplifies the problem and i did the same after getting no option.!
Thanks for your valuable time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Promise.all method, which returns a promise when all promises have been fulfilled. And this final promise will have all the collections you asked for.

this is example for firestore function on express

```
app.get("/endpoint/:id", async (request, response) => {
    const id = request.params.id
    const collectionSnapshot = await 
      db.collection(collection).doc(id).get()
    const [collection] = await Promise.all([
      async () => {
        const collectionData = collectionSnapshot.data()
        const subCollectionSnapshot = await db
         .collection(subCollection)
         .where("collection_id", "==", collectionData.id)
         .get()
      return {
        ...collection,
        subCollection,
    }
  },
])

const collectionData = await collection()

// Send collection and subCollection data to the client
response.status(200).send({ data: { ...collectionData } })
```

})