# How to query 'nestedbyId' collections in Firestore, and show it in the async pipe, corresponding it correctly?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 root collections, and want to retrieve joined data by ID, these are the collections;
What I want and also strutcture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpsGn.jpg (in the 'Item' field I want to show the 'nome' of 'produto', instead of the ID related)

htmlFile

```
<ion-list >

  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let pProduto of pedidoProdutos | async">

    <ion-item>
      <h3 class="text-align">Item: {{pProduto.nome}}</h3> 
      <h3 class="text-align">Quantidade: {{pProduto.quantidade}}</h3> 
      <h3 class="text-align">Valor Total: {{pProduto.valor}}</h3> 
    </ion-item>


    <ion-item-options side="right">

      <button ion-button icon-only color="danger" (click)="remover(pProduto.id)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </button>

    </ion-item-options>

  </ion-item-sliding>

</ion-list>
```

tsFile

```
  private pProdutos:string;

  private pedidoProdutoCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<ProdutosPedido>;
  private pedidoProdutos: Observable<ProdutosPedido[]>;
  this.pProdutos = this.pmt.getPedido();

  this.pedidoProdutoCollection = this.db.collection<ProdutosPedido>('produtosPedidos', ref => {
    return ref.where('pedido', '==', this.pProdutos)
  });
  this.pedidoProdutos = this.pedidoProdutoCollection.valueChanges();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Cloud function how can i join from another collection to get data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347676/in-cloud-function-how-can-i-join-from-another-collection-to-get-data)

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Comment: it is JS, I don't understand it clearly

Comment: In my answer, there is nothing related to JS. I just explained the principles.

Comment: I mean, im able to get all the 'produto'(id) of 'produtosPedido', but how do I show the 'nome' related to the id in the async pipe together??

Comment: By creating another database call to get the `nome` that corresponds to that id.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can get Isolated 'nome', but I want to show it in the async pipe, corresponding to the item list (its a shopping cart), how to proceed?

Comment: I don't want to duplicate data, even though this is the easiest way