# How to perform trigger Firebase Cloud Function on same day and month only (Like birthday)?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to send notification to few users through Firebase Cloud Function on his / hier birthday. I have user's device token Id and birthdate (as date) in database. I checked some script on stackoverflow, but its not helpful because birthdate and today have only dd/MM are similar. Year is always different.

I tried this ([How to trigger function when date stored in firestore database is todays date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323163/how-to-trigger-function-when-date-stored-in-firestore-database-is-todays-date)) script but its not working.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const moment = require('moment');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendDailyNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    cors(request, response, () => {

       const now = moment();
       const dateFormatted = now.format('DDMMYYYY');

       admin.firestore()
       .collection("userCollection").where("birthDate", "==", dateFormatted)
       .get()
       .then(function(querySnapshot) {

           const promises = []; 

           querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

               const tokenId = doc.data().tokenId;
               const notificationContent = {
                 notification: {
                    title: "...",
                    body: "...",
                    icon: "default",
                    sound : "default"
                 }
              };

              promises
              .push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, notificationContent));      

          });
          return Promise.all(promises);
       })
       .then(results => {
            response.send(data)
       })
       .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          response.status(500).send(error)
       });

    });

});
```

I want to trigger this function on user's birthday. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but its not working.". What is not working? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You've written an HTTP trigger.  It will run whenever the HTTP endpoint is accessed.  It cannot possibly run automatically on a certain day or time, so without something else that invokes this function on the schedule you want, nothing will happen.

If you want to periodically check your database for changes, you can write a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that queries your database for work to do every day, then performs it.

Comment: and @ Renauld Tarnec, Extremely sorry for poor code. Actually I really don't know even basics of Firebase Cloud Functions. 

Can you give me example for my case? I want to send push notification to users on his / her birthday. I have user's birthday as dd/MM/yyyy in document and Token id in other document.

Please help me.